# How do i get values from a html for python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get all my flash numbers from a steam website that its code is like this:

```
                                                        <div id="personaldata_elements_container">
                                <table class="generic_kv_table"><tr><td>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Match Time: 2020-12-04 01:50:07 GMT     </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Game Mode: Competitive      </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Map: de_mirage      </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Starting CT Side: Não       </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Match Completed: Sim        </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Match Result: Win       </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Match Score: 16:13      </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Kills: 25       </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Headshots: 14       </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        2K Rounds: 6        </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        3K Rounds: 2        </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Damage Dealt: 2470      </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Deaths: 17      </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        MVPs: 3     </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Personal Score: 57      </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        1v1 Success: 2/2        </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        1v2 Success: 0/1        </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        HE Success: 0/1     </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Flash Success: 12/20        </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
        Entry Duels Success: 2/4        </div>
        <div class="generic_kv_line">
```

I want to get the Flash Success: numbers how do I do it? this is my code:

```
table = soup.find('div', {'id': 'personaldata_elements_container'})
tds = table.find_all('table', {'class': 'generic_kv_table'})[1]


josh = tds.find('div', {'class': 'generic_kv_line'})

parker = tds.get("Flash Success:")
print(parker)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `:contains()` CSS Selector: `.generic_kv_line:contains("Flash Success")`, this searches for the class `generic_kv_line` which has the text `Flash Success`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.select('.generic_kv_line:contains("Flash Success")'):
    print(tag.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
Flash Success: 12/20
```

Comment: Thank you! Since it's matches history page it has a lot of "Flash Sucess:" and when i do your method it prints me two results for it, is there anyway to combine both into 1 result? for example instead of being: Flash Success: 12/20
Flash Success: 2/14, Just Flash Success:14/34

Comment: @dLoop Sorry, I don't fully understand you're question. Try appending the results to a list, and print the list